# How to align a face to a position in world space?

Tags: python, math, 3d, blender, mesh

I have a mathematical problem. Let's say I have a face (with 3 or 4 vertices) at some world position. I want to translate/rotate the mesh so that the face is "facing" up and is centered (0,y,0). What is the formula(s) needed to pull this off?

[image: Face at original position] [image: Face at desired position]

I can do this with a gui (this example was simply an x rotation of appx -90 degrees), however I need to do this via a script so I need to know how this can be done mathematically.

EDIT:
I should also note that these vectors are part of a mesh which I'm wanting to rotate (origin at (0,0,0)) till v1 is at position v2.

Here's the pseudo code that is failing:

```
v1 = vector(0,10,0)
v2 = vector(0,-10,0)

v1 = normalize(v1)
v2 = normalize(v2)

cross = normalize( v2.cross(v1) )  // (0,0,0)
angle = acos( v2.dot(v1) )  // 180

quat  = quaternion(cross,angle) // {w:1,x:0,y:0,z:0}
```

I would have thought the quaternion would be something like: {w:?,x:3.14159,y:0,z:0} or {w:?,x:0,y:0,z:3.14159}

Comment: Are you just trying to align along an axis? If you don't care if it keeps the exact same size, just average the vertices along the y axis and set the y value for the vertices to that value. Then clear out x and z to 0.

Comment: I want the vertex at position a to move to position b by rotating/translating the mesh.

Comment: Exactly, I'm sure the math below is spot on, but turning that into a function...oh boy.

Comment: A quaternion is represented as <w,x,y,z> where <w> represents the angle (PI in this case), and <x,y,z> is the axis by which you are rotating around.  The quaternion you are expecting looks something like <PI,?,?,?>, however it won't quite be that because that isn't normalized.

Comment: Ah was wondering what the "w" was hehe thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with either a rotation matrix or quaternions, however I would suggest the rotation matrix route because you can simultaneously solve all of the points with a single matrix multiplication.

**Rotation Matrix:** If you know what what euler angles you wish to rotate about, then a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is the way to go.  To form a rotation matrix, see the "Basic Rotations" section of the link.  Rather than knowing what "up" is, you need to know how much you wish to rotate your object.  In this case (judging from the photos provided), you want to rotate 90 degrees about the *global* x axis (if you wish to do it about a *local* axis, you must know the current orientation of the object.  I can elaborate in an edit if you need *local* rotations).  Your *global* rotation matrix will be:

```
[1  0  0]
[0  0  1]
[0 -1  0]
```

I calculated this from using the Rx(90) matrix in the "Basic Rotations" section.  Now, form your 3D points in column vectors.  Let's say one point is at (0,0,1).  This point is directly where the nose would be, so we expect the transformed point to be (0,1,0).  Simply left multiply the rotation matrix to get your result:

```
[1  0  0] [0] [0]
[0  0  1]*[0]=[1]
[0 -1  0] [1] [0]
```

Note that in this case the transformation is fairly trivial; we are simply shifting the coordinates around (x stays the same, y is negated, z and y are swapped).  You can simultaneously transform a large set of points by horizontally concatenating all of the initial coordinates to form a 3xN matrix and then left multiplying the rotation matrix.  For instance, let's transform the points { (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,0,-1) }:

```
[1  0  0] [0  0  1  0] [0  0  1  0]
[0  0  1]*[0  1  0  0]=[1  0  1  0]
[0 -1  0] [1  0  1 -1] [0 -1  0  1]
```

As a reminder, this transform rotates about the global origin (as illustrated by the (1,0,1) point).  You will have to subtract the centroid of your coordinates, rotate, then add the final translation coordinates.

**Quaternion:** I can give a tutorial here, but this is often referred to as "axis-angle" notation; you can use it to create a rotation matrix that will rotate your points about an arbitrary unit axis by a specified angle.  [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html) is a great tutorial for that.  Let me know if I should elaborate in an edit.

EDIT: in response to the added pseudo code

If the cross product is 0, then the lines are parallel.  The axis of rotation can be ANY vector perpendicular to EITHER input (which makes it perpendicular to both by definition).  A vector p is defined as perpendicular if dot(v,p)==0, or v.x*p.x+v.y*p.y+v.z*p.z==0 and length(p)>0, so we can arbitrarily choose any solution that satisfies these equations.

```
v1 = vector(0,10,0)
v2 = vector(0,-10,0)

//Not necessary, since you will normalize the cross product result
//v1 = normalize(v1)
//v2 = normalize(v2)

cross = v2.cross(v1)  // (0,0,0) and possible divide by 0 if normalized here
if(length(cross)==0){ //either "==0" or "<thresh" where thresh is some very small number
   if(v.z!=0)
        cross = vector(1,1,-(v1.x+v1.y)/v1.z);
   else if(v.y!=0) //is z==0?  well here's an identical solution as long as y isn't 0
        cross = vector(1,-(v1.x+v1.z)/v.y,1);
   else //by this point, v1.x must be the only nonzero remaining point, otherwise it's a null vector
        cross = vector(-(v1.y+v1.z)/v.x,1,1);
}
cross=normalize(cross);
angle = acos( normalize(v2.dot(v1)) )  // 180

quat  = quaternion(cross,angle)
```

I'm not familiar with python code, so I added the C++ equivalent.  If someone could edit this post to correct it, that'd be superb.

Edit: I didn't see your comment about acos, sorry about that.  Changed the code accordingly.

Comment: I really wish I understood this more. I'm still battling with this. I'm doing this in a programming language (python) and am having a hard time  converting what you posted into a function. I've stumbled upon angle = acos(dot(v1,v2)). That seems to work some times. I get the correct angle from (0,-1,0) and (0,1,0) => 180, but when I do (0,-2,0) and (0,2,0) the acos function breaks since in that case dot(v1,v2) is no longer 0 - 1. Eck I'm so confused. I should have made the disclaimer that I am not good at this type of math at all =[

Comment: I was able to get the acos(dot(v1,v2)) function to stop breaking by normalizing the vectors prior. But from some reason that I do not understand the quaternion between v1 (0,1,0) and v2 (0,-1,0) is {w:1, x:0, y:0, z:0} even though arcos(dot(v1,v2)) is returning PI. I would have thought either the x or z rotation would be PI.

Comment: If you are finding the axis by which to rotate via cross product, you have to make sure that your cross product doesn't result in (0,0,0) (in the example you provided, it does!).  Additionally, double check to make sure you are diving the angle by 2 when calculating the quaternion (PI/2 in this case).  If these are not the correct fix, try to post some code in an edit to the OP.

Comment: Right! The cross product in this situation is (0,0,0) which is confusing me.

Comment: Edited the answer to catch the parallel vector case, but it's not tested so it may not be totally right lol.

Comment: It's completely arbitrary, so yes if you want it to be ^.^