# Making a Face of a 3D Mesh Face "Up" in Blender (Python)

Tags: python, 3d, rotation, blender, mesh

I have been struggling with this for a couple weeks now. How can I get a selected face of an object to point "up"? Is there a built in function to make this simple? Will I have to take more math classes to figure this out lol?

I basically want to rotate a mesh so the one selected face I chose is facing "up" (so the face centroid x and z are at 0 with the face normal pointing straight up).

[image: initital position] [image: target position]

The origin of the mesh will be at (0,0,0)

Obviously this is simple to do using Blenders GUI, but how would one automate this process in python?

The reason I am doing this is to do displacement mapping on a selected face. I've noticed blender does this by projecting the image down at (0,0,0) at least in "GLOBAL" mode. When I use the default "LOCAL" mode for the displacement modifier things go crazy for some reason. I cannot use UV mode since some meshes will not have UV's.

Please somebody help me.

Comment: This is identical to your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247177/how-to-align-a-face-to-a-position-in-world-space)

Comment: Not really, I'm specifically asking how to do it using Blender operations.